# Load data from DB2 by flat file

Tags: sql, db2, database-migration

I have data sample from SQL server 2008, I want to move all data to DB2. I'm using DCW tool kit of ibm. When I selected Load Data from Database Convention[image: error message]

Is there something wrong? I'm loggin to database by admin account.

Comment: Are you remotely connected to DB2

Comment: Yes, I'm using data studio for working.

Comment: error is suggesting that you should move the file to the machine in which db2 is install

Comment: Thanks for suggest me! I'll find another way to import data to db2.